# Draw flow chart in SDI MFC application

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, gdi+, gdi

I am working on a client/server application in c++. In the server application I am running multiple server IP's and I want to show a flow chart in the server app which has to display the connected clients with some basic shapes like rectangle and circle. Can anybody tell how Can I achieve this? Is there any MFC classes available

Comment: If at all possible, try to find an alternative for MFC. It's totally outdated.

Comment: @RalphTandetzky: Completely unfounded opinion, sorry. MFC is still, to this date, the only officially supported C++-based framework for Windows development. It is neither outdated, nor are there any capable alternatives (maybe with the exception of WTL). In this specific case, MFC provides all the tools you need to implement this (namely a DC wrapper, unsurprisingly called [CDC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxhhde73.aspx)).

Comment: @IInspectable Of course there are alternatives for Windows gui frameworks in C++: You can use all of .NET including WinForms and WPF, if that tickles your fancy and you want to stay within Microsoft space. Otherwise Qt and WxWidgets provide portable solutions that will also work on other operating systems. For more alternatives see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115045/good-c-gui-library-for-windows.

Comment: @RalphTandetzky: There is no native C++-based interface for Windows Forms or WPF, nor is there a C++-based framework. You could use C++/CLI, but that'd still just control a managed interface through managed code. wxWidget is lacking support. And Qt fails the *"capable"* part. Even a properly written Qt application fails to deliver a quality UI (the kind you **can** implement using MFC). At any rate, what specific feature is MFC missing to implement a solution to this question's problem?

Comment: @IInspectable I didn't want to start a flame war on opinions, so I'm sorry for the first comment, which might have been a bit harsh. I know, that MFC is still supported by Microsoft, even though Microsoft's emphasis shifted towards .NET gui components. MFC started in 1992 and inherits a lot of legacy from that time. I'm working with Qt a lot and I find it very capable of providing professionally designed user interfaces. I'm not saying that MFC is missing any particular feature.

Comment: @RalphTandetzky: If you intend to implement a keyboard UI for your application (and I hope you do), you cannot use Qt. It's implementation is broken (and cannot be fixed), and you'll see your application losing input focus sooner or later. I have yet to find a single Qt application that is lucky enough to never do this. A proper keyboard interface adds to the quality of an application, and MFC can deliver in this department. Qt cannot.

Answer (score 0):

I made such an application in the past, but it was in WinApi only, not MFC. For each client connecting to the server there was displayed a small dialog (with the "child" flag set - it had its own controls, of course). Displaying "basic shapes" can be implemented by custom drawing on owner-drawn controls. And MFC provides a number of "wrapper" classes and functions, encapsulating WinApi objects but still allowing access to these API-level objects and calls, ie everyhting that can be implemented in WinApi can be implemented in MFC as well. Still, MFC isn't "necessary" or "recommended" here.

Screenshot of the application I was talking about. Take a look at the sunken "static" owner-drawn controls (`SS_SUNKEN | SS_OWNERDRAW`), emulating the appearance of a LED indicator.

[image]